# Sverchok beginner: Viewer draw Mk3: How to connect faces and edges to vertices?

Tags: sverchok

I'm working through the [Sverchock introduction tutorial](http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/Unit_01/lesson_01.html) and I see a lot has changed in version 0.6. But i am able to do what it says. Only the last part:

> Now if you change the slider on the Float node, you’ll notice 2
> things: 1. the header of the Float node gets the value of the slider, and
> 2. more importantly, the Polygon will start to increase and decrease in
> size because you are multiplying the x, y, and z components of the
> Vectors by that amount.

2. The polygon (face) does not increase or decrease in size.

If I disconnect the edges and/or face from the Viewer, then I can see the vertices scale when I slide.
When I bake the plane again, the edges and faces are duplicated and take the size of the Scalar.

Why does the scale not apply to the faces/edges and why do they behave like different objects?

[image: vertices scale when edges/faces are disconnected]
[image: No edges and vertices to be seen, not scaleable]

Comment: I think you pressed "bake" on the Viewer Draw node, that writes the mesh to the 3dview as an object. The tutorial doesn't tell you to hit bake  :)  You will only be using the viewer node to show a "virtual" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow the tutorials here instead:

start here

- [00/soft_intro_01](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/Unit_00/soft_intro_01.rst)
- [01/lesson_01](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/Unit_01/lesson_01.rst)
- [01/notes](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/nesting.rst) (notes for lesson 02)
- [01/lesson_02](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/Unit_01/lesson_02.rst)
- [01/lesson_03](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/blob/master/docs/Unit_01/lesson_03.rst)

i'll try to update the online manual (compiled "read.thedocs") soon.

---

to address your progress in the tutorial, when you use that number node to scale the vertices, they are indeed scaling. If you look carefully, you see even in the image that the white-dots (vertices) are scaling outwards. In the top example.

In the bottom example, the input into the node is not correct. The node in the tutorial you are following (the old viewer node) handles the same input differently, you'll notice the old node had a socket that accepted both Edges and Faces/Polygons at the same time.  The New ViewerDrawMK3 node however has separate sockets for edges and faces and also reads the socket data differently. The node has gone *red* to indicate a problem with the input, it will do nothing until the input is corrected.

You will ( i am sure ) have better luck following the tutorial updated for b.28. Which i linked to above.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Comment: Links in the Answer aren't correct anymore

Answer (score 0):

And also.
When you select both nodes, press V and it joins similar names sockets (pols, polygons,faces are the same)